# jndi-name of infinispan cache container is not valid anymore with wildfly 15

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jndi, infinispan

after migrating from jboss as 7 to wildfly 15 jndi-name of infinispan cache container is not valid anymore with wildfly 15.

```
OPVDX001: Validierungsfehler in standalone.xml ---------------------------------
|
|  344: 
|  345:         <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:7.0">
|  346:             <cache-container jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/my-container" name="my-container" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
|                                           "cache-container"
|                                    ^^^^ "jndi-name" ist kein zulässiges Attribut für das Element
|                                         
|                                         Die folgenden Attribute sind hier zulässig: aliases, default-cache,
|                                           module, name, statistics-enabled 
|
|  347:                 <local-cache  name="my-other-container">
|  348:                     <expiration lifespan="900000" />
|  349:                 </local-cache>
|
| "jndi-name" ist zulässig bei Elementen:
```

is there a replacement for jndi-name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Property "jndi-name" is deleted. Just declare the property "name".

Then you can lookup the container using the pattern below. The container is available in JDNI context with this lookup path: `java:jboss/infinispan/container/<your-container-name>/`

**Sample config:**

```
<cache-container name="my-container" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
    <local-cache name="lala" >
      <object-memory size="10000"/>
      <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

instead of

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/my-container")
private EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;
```

use

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/my-container/"
private EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;
```

or direct inject cache

```
// java:jboss/infinispan/cache/<name-of-container>/<name-of-cache>
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/my-container/lala")
private Cache<String, PrincipalEntity> userCache;
```

**see also:**

[wildscribe subsystem infinispan](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/15.0/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/index.html)

[related issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9463)

[image: WFLY-9463]